# Assuming variables are real and positive

Tags: syntax

I thought the following code would work,

```
Clear[a, h]
$Assumptions = Element[{a, h}, Reals && a > 0 && h > 0]
s = 3 a;
b = 2 a;
h = h /. Solve[{h^2 + b^2 == s^2}, h]
```

but $h$ is still set to a list.

This worked;

```
Clear[a, h]
s = 3 a;
b = 2 a;
h = h /. Solve[{h^2 + b^2 == s^2 && h > 0 && a > 0}, h, Reals] // Simplify // Normal
```

but cannot all the assumptions be made in advance, instead of an argument to `Solve`? TIA.

Comment: 1. `Solve` does not have an `Assumptions` option so it is not affected by `$Assumptions` (`Simplify` is) 2. You have a syntax error: placed `&& a>0` inside of `Element`

Comment: I don't spot the syntax error. Could you write the correct command. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the constraints with the equation, and also use them with `Simplify` to unwrap the resulting `ConditionalExpression`:

```
Clear[a, h]
constraints = a > 0 && h > 0;
s = 3 a;
b = 2 a;
h = Simplify[h /. Solve[h^2 + b^2 == s^2 && constraints, h], 
  Assumptions -> constraints]
(* {Sqrt[5] a} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `FullSimplify` to add the consumptions

```
s = 3 a;
b = 2 a;
Reduce[{h^2 + b^2 == s^2}, h]~FullSimplify~{a > 0, h > 0}
```